# Connect Talend to Salesforce using OAuth JWT Flow in Talend v6.2

Tags: integration, connected-apps, talend

I followed the steps exactly mentioned here https://help.talend.com/reader/jomWd_GKqAmTZviwG_oxHQ/a8jLl7sBZvEIsAkL1wTiGA for connecting Talend v6.2 to salesforce.
[image]
The documentation states that we need to add 'Token File': the path to the token file that stores the refresh token used to get the access token without authorization.

But I am not getting **how to generate Token File**. Please help.

Comment: I think the answer is to run the job first and then get the file as mentioned on [Talend Community](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/Using-OAuth-connection-type-to-Access-Salesforce-via-Talend-Data/td-p/46912).

Comment: I don't think that this is a Salesforce question though, is a Talend specific config.

Comment: The documentation states that we need a token file that stores the refresh token used by the OAuth-enabled connected app. So how to get this token file?

Comment: @DerekF issue mentioned by you is for Talend v7.1.1